# How do I get all computer's name and IP address in ListView using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, networking

How do I get all computer's name and IP address which connected to network including (LAN & Wifi) in ListView using VB.NET?

Comment: Are you trying to make a GUI interface using visual basic to track the killer's IP address?

Comment: I try to make GUI Interface using vb.net to view all computers name and ip address which connected to my network.@Evan

Comment: You'll need to ask a specific question about why some code you wrote isn't working or ask a specific question.  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Computer Name:

```
My.Computer.Name
```

IP Addresses (your computer probably has more than 1 adapter and each adapter can have more than 1 address):

```
    For Each i As Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface In Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
        Dim props As Net.NetworkInformation.IPInterfaceProperties = i.GetIPProperties
        For Each addr As Net.NetworkInformation.UnicastIPAddressInformation In props.UnicastAddresses
            Debug.WriteLine(addr.Address.ToString)
        Next
    Next
```